# Website dashboard design(guidelines to follow)

Tags: gui-design, ux-designer, dashboard

We are currently having landing page as below.

- There are 'x' number of entities, each entity is displayed as a square,4 in each row
- All the information related to that entity will be displayed inside the square

Problems

- As the number of entities gets increased,the number of squares also gets increased and it doesn't look good on UI and UX is also not that great.

What kind of design i should follow here to improve UI and UX.
I can provide more info and screenshots if needed.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Even one screenshot would help alot!

Comment: @LisaTweedie added screenshot

Comment: What is the maximum and minimum of items displayed?

Comment: minimun is 4,maximum is between 15-20

Comment: My first impressions, the text is too small and difficult to read (lack of contrast betwene the white and green) and there is a lot of whitespace between the columns.

Comment: Why have you removed the image? Can you explain what the squares do? Are they just info squares or can users make actions on them?

Comment: I got to know the info was confidential after uploading,They are not just info squares, one of each square represents each group, when you click on any of the group, it will go to a page where user can see sub-groups related to the selected group.

Comment: Can't you just remove the information and replace it with dummy text? After all, we only need to see some text on some squares arranged how they were in order to understand the question. white text on blue squares is not confidential.

Comment: yeah i understand what you are saying, i am currently preparing a dummy page with similar design, once it's done i will attach again.

Answer (score 2):

It's not 100% clear from your question, if you could add any other contextual details it would probably be helpful.

### The route you want to go down is: grouping.

Start out by trying to group certain entities if possible. You could then implement filters, folders or color coding to allow your users to better make sense and categorize your data.

*Edit:* for example you could group squares by connected and not connected PCs.

See the example below:

[image]

The entities are divided into sections which makes it much easier for the users to find the information they want.

But then again, (and this is where your question fails to provide context) you don't tell us what these entities do... Are they just info boxes or can the users make actions on them?

Comment: Yes, maybe group by connected and not connected pcs

Comment: @rhauger Good point. I edited it into the answer, thanks.

Comment: Grouping by connected and disconnected PCs is not the correct way to do it because the number varies from entity to entity, we are thinking of grouping the entities based on their functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is solved many many times in UX design. It is simply the problem of having too much information so then you need a different view.
Allow the user to control the view by giving them options. You won't know their viewport.

Responsive design blogs will have lots of solutions for this because the most difficult example is going from the web to a mobile interface. Your solution should be responsive to the data so the view could alter depending on how many items they are.

The Apple finder is a good place to start though - here the user is provided with different views at the top and when they are selected they are clearly displayed.

Image view:
[image: Apple finder image view]

File view:
[image]

Another way is to use an accordian list - so minimal information is provide on small cards each of which can be opened

[image: Accordian list in balsamiq]

Just look about you and find some examples they are everywhere!

Just a note on your current design ... there is a lot of whitespace betwen the columns! And the typography could do with some work - different font choices and sizes could really improve this. White on blue is not very readable either.